# Check for Drop Down List in WKWebView in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode7, wkwebview

I am currently developing a responsive Hybrid application.
Do we know how to get the drop down lists working in WKWebView ? It currently does not respond to the touch and selects the first item in the list without pulling up the drop down list.
I know this is working in UIWebView but does not work in WKWebView.
Any Ideas are appreciated.

Updated with HTML Code:

```
<ul id="select-list" class="select-list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" style="top: 18px; width: 235px; display: block;"><li id="list-option0" role="option" class="select-option is-selected" tabindex="-1">Choose</li><li id="list-option1" role="option" class="select-option" tabindex="-1">Number1</li></ul>
```

More Updates:
Document onResize from Javascript is called when using WKWebKit and not UIWekKit.

Comment: Please be more specific. Like post some `HTML` code for an example drop down that does not work.

Comment: I have updated the code in the above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a drop down. That is a list turned into a drop down. I think for best mobile compatibility you want a normal `select` element.

Comment: Yeah true...But the main reason was for some reason in WKWebKit we are receiving Document onResize call in javascript which is causing the issue.